# How to style Windows Form Labels

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am writing a (purely) PowerShell app to display numbers in a table using Windows Forms

My thought is to create rows of fixed-size labels (or text boxes), which works out just fine. What I am having trouble with is figuring how to make those numbers right-justified within each label field. I see that using XAML there is a "HorizontalContentAlignment" but I can't seem to see the equivalent property in PowerShell. I see there is TextAlign property but that seems to be for **Vertical** alignment, rather than Horizontal.

Of course, I am open to doing something else (other than table of labels) that'll do the same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: `TextAlign` is for both vertical and horizontal alignment. `TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight` is probably what you need.

Comment: have you considered: `get-help Out-GridView -examples`?

Comment: Keep in mind that XAML has nothing to do with Winforms, XAML is used in WPF and UWP to generate a GUI so having properties available in XAML means nothing in this context.

Comment: When I said XAML I was referring to the XAML created by VisualStudio when you start a WPF project. Just too lazy to write all that out and assumed seasoned professionals would understand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can use the enumerations from `System.Drawing.ContentAlignment`

```
$Label = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = 'SomeText'
$Label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleRight
```

- How did I find the peroperty ?

  ```
  $Label | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.name -like "*ali*"}
  ```

Comment: :) That was going to be my next question: How to find out what properties were called.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are writing an app only with Powershell, I'd think it would be a little weird using Win Forms just for displaying information.
I'd suggest checking out POSHGUI (https://poshgui.com/Editor) which helps you generate win forms style GUI for you're Powershell code.
In addition, Powershell has Out-Gridview, which could be sufficient to your need if I got the idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I will definitely look at POSHGUI and Out-GridView for other projects. I wanted to use WinForms partly as a way to learn WinForms. And partly because I wanted to be able to update the numbers (it's a monitoring app) in-place rather than scrolling the table of numbers.